# Jan Ullrich's TT bike in la Vuelta 1999: why the bigger rear wheel?

Tags: road-bike, rear-wheel, racing, time-trial

What was the thinking behind having a bigger rear wheel on a TT bike back then?

[image: The barbie bike]

Comment: @carel: moved to https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/q/69758/19705

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The rear wheel is normal size (700), the front wheel is smaller (650). It was for aerodynamic reasons. By lowering the torso of the rider, the frontal surface of the rider became smaller.

The configuration appeared first in triathlon and was later banned by the UCI in road and track events. Both wheels must now be of identical size i.e. 700.

Comment: In addition to lowering the profile of the rider and the bike, I'd bet the smaller front wheel is not only more aerodynamic than a larger wheel, it's also less affected by crosswinds.

Comment: @AndrewHenle yes - and though not possible in a TT, a smaller front wheel lets you draught closer to the rider in front for more gain.

Comment: @Criggie: Individual TT it was, no drafting permitted there!

Comment: Can you add why it was banned to your answer?

Comment: @RockPaperLz-MaskitorCasket The UCI banned it. Since I did not sit on the panel when it was done, I don't know the specific reason. They just did it in the way they banned other things. Like certain sock lengths of handlebar ad-ons.

Comment: @Criggie: A smaller wheel is also less stable due to the smaller gyroscopic effect.

Comment: @carel that might be a positive, if it were a race bike where "responsive handling" is perceived as beneficial.  In a TT there's advantage in a long bike with good straight-line handling over "fast to change direction" aka "twitchy race handling"

Comment: Biggest mistake i ever made was having a low-profile frame for 24-inch front and 700c rear built to replace my stolen racing bike. I hated that frame (whereas the stolen one was the best bike I have ever had).